# Several data sources in one spring integration pipeline?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a configured spring integration pipeline where xml files are parsed into various objects. The objects are going through several channel endpoints where they are slightly modified - nothing special, just some properties added.

The last endpoint from the pipeline is the persister, where the objects are persisted in DB. There might be duplicates, so in this endpoint there is also a check whether the object is already persisted or its a new one.
I use a message driven architecture, with simple direct channels.

```
<int:channel id="parsedObjects1" />
<int:channel id="parsedObjects2" />
<int:channel id="processedObjects" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="parsedObjects1" ref="processor1" method="process" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="parsedObjects2" ref="processor2" method="process" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="processedObjects" ref="persister" method="persist" />
```

In the moment there is only one data source, from where I get xml files, and everything is going smoothly. The problems begin when I need to attach a second data source. The files are coming in the same time so I want them processed in parallel. So, I've placed two parser instances, and every parser is sending messages through the pipeline.
The configuration with the direct channels that I have creates concurrency problems, so I've tried modifying it. I've tried several configuration from spring integration documentation, but so far with no success.

I've tried with dispatcher configured with max pool size of 1 - one thread per message in every channel endpoint.

```
<task:executor id="channelTaskExecutor" pool-size="1-1" keep-alive="10" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" queue-capacity="1" />
<int:channel id="parsedObjects1" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" />
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="parsedObjects2" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" />
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="processedObjects" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" />
</int:channel>
```

I have tried the queue-poller configuration also:

```
<task:executor id="channelTaskExecutor" pool-size="1-1" keep-alive="10" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" queue-capacity="1" />
<int:channel id="parsedObjects1" >
    <int:rendezvous-queue/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="parsedObjects2" >
    <int:rendezvous-queue/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="processedObjects" >
    <int:rendezvous-queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="parsedObjects1" ref="processor1" method="process" >
    <int:poller task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="1"  fixed-rate="2" />
</int:service-activator>
<int:service-activator input-channel="parsedObjects2" ref="processor2" method="process" >
    <int:poller task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="1"  fixed-rate="2" />
</int:service-activator>
<int:service-activator input-channel="processedObjects" ref="persister" method="persist" >
    <int:poller task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="1"  fixed-rate="2" />
</int:service-activator>
```

Basically, I want to get rid of any race conditions in the channel endpoints - in my case in the persister. The persister channel endpoint should block for every message, because if it runs in parallel, I get many duplicates persisted in the DB.

EDIT:

After some debugging I've done, it seems that the problems are in the endpoints logic rather than the configuration. Some of the objects which are sent through the pipeline to the persister, are also stored in a local cache until parsing of the file is done - they are later sent through the pipeline as well to persist some join tables as a part of some other domain entities. It happens that with the above configurations, some of the objects were not yet persisted when they are sent for the second time in the pipeline, so at the end I get duplicates in the DB.
I'm fairly new at spring integration, so probably at this point I will ask more general questions. In a setup with multiple data sources - meaning multiple instances of parsers etc:

1. Is there a common way (best way) to go to configure the pipeline to enable parallelization?
2. If there is need, is there a way to serialize the message handling?

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, can you describe what the "concurrency problems" are? Ideally you would not need to serialize the message handling, so that would be a good place to start.

Second, the thread pool as you've configured it will not completely serialize. You will have 1 thread available *in the pool* but the rejection policy you've chosen leads to a caller thread running the task itself (basically throttling) in the case that the queue is at capacity. That means you will get a caller-run thread concurrently with the one from the pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look into the dispatcher configuration again. I also edited my question to clear out some things.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think of for your scenario would be along these lines:

Make your parsedObject1 and parsedObject2 be normal queue channels, the capacity of the queue can be set appropriately (say 25 at any time):

```
<int:channel id="parsedObjects1" >
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
```

Now at this point your xml processors against the 2 channels - parsedObjects1 and parsedObjects2, will process the xml's and should output to the `processedObjects` channel. You can use the configuration similar to what you have for this, except that I have explicitly specified the processedObjects channel -:

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="parsedObjects1" ref="processor1" method="process" output-channel="processedObjects">
    <int:poller task-executor="channelTaskExecutor"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

The third step is where I will deviate from your configuration, at this point you said you want to serialize the persistence, the best way would be to do it through a DIFFERENT task executor with a pool size of 1, this way only 1 instance of your persister is running at any point in time:

```
<task:executor id="persisterpool" pool-size="1"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="processedObjects" ref="persister" method="persist" >
    <int:poller task-executor="persisterpool" fixed-delay="2"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I managed to get it working. I'm not sure whether it's the right way , I will experiment some more and try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the pipeline working. I'm not sure if I'll keep the current configuration, or experiment some more, but for now, this is the configuration I ended up with:

```
<task:executor id="channelTaskExecutor" pool-size="1-1" keep-alive="10" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" queue-capacity="1" />
<int:channel id="parsedObjects1" >
<int:queue capacity="1000" />
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="parsedObjects2" >
<int:queue capacity="1000" />
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="processedObjects" >
<int:queue capacity="1000" />
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="parsedObjects1" ref="processor1" method="process" >
<int:poller task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="100"  fixed-rate="2" />
</int:service-activator>
<int:service-activator input-channel="parsedObjects2" ref="processor2" method="process" >
<int:poller task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="100"  fixed-rate="2" />
</int:service-activator>
<int:service-activator input-channel="processedObjects" ref="persister" method="persist" >
<int:poller task-executor="channelTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="1"  fixed-rate="2" />
</int:service-activator>
```